# How do I get UNIX diff to ignore duplicate lines in different positions?

Tags: unix, csv, diff

I have two CSV files about 134 mb.

All I want to do is get the 'diff' of the two files, except the position of a line doesn't matter.

In other words, let's say I have:

```
abc,123
def,456
```

and

```
def,456
ghi,789
```

I don't want to be told about def,456.  It's in a different position in the second file, but I want it to be counted as not being different.

Just doing diff file1 file2 > outputfile isn't working.  What command should I use to do this?  I know this is trivial in PHP but I run out of memory quickly.  I'd rather just use UNIX command line tools.  Diff may not even be the right utility for this.

Comment: is the order of the files important?  if not, you could sort them first before diff?

Comment: I'm confused because those two example files are sorted already.  It's going to compare abc,123 to def,456 and say it's different, even though def,456 occurs in both files.

Comment: When I diff the above I get 1d0
< abc,123
2a2
> ghi,789
It does not mention def as being different.  You want them sorted so that hopefully matching lines line up close enough to avoid being reported as different.

Comment: You're right, ribram.  Sorting and then doing diff does fix this issue for the examples, but I think the two CSV's in question have another problem entirely.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose that you do a `sort` on the two input files and then compare the two sorted versions, something like this:

```
sort file1 > sorted_1
sort file2 > sorted_2

diff sorted_1 sorted_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, what diff does is identify differences like that. I think what you want is a tool that identifies:

```
1
2
3
```

and:

```
3
1
2
```

as being the same. There is no tool I know of that does this (but I might add it to to my http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/ tool at some point).

What you currently need to do is sort both files and then diff them.